# How to give Promise to For Loop in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

How to stop nodeJS to execute statements written outside for loop till for loop is completed?

```
for(i=0;i<=countFromRequest;i++)
{
    REQUEST TO MODEL => then getting result here (its an object)
    licensesArray.push(obj.key);
}
res.status(200).send({info:"Done Releasing Bulk Licenses!!!",licensesArray:licensesArray})
```

The problem is that the statement after For Loop is being executed before For loop, so the licensesArray is empty when i receive the API Data.

Any clue how to do that?

Will be thankful to you.

Comment: You need to `await` the request to the model. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **async/await**:

```
const licensesArray = [];

for(let i = 0; i <= countFromRequest; i++) {
    const obj = await requestModel(); // wait for model and get resolved value
    licensesArray.push(obj.key);
}

res.status(200).send({licensesArray});
```

Using `Promise.all`:

```
const pArr = [];
const licensesArray = [];

for(let i = 0; i <= countFromRequest; i++) {
    pArr.push(requestModel().then(obj => {
        licensesArray.push(obj.key);
    }));
}

Promise.all(pArr).then(() => { // wait for all promises to resolve
    res.status(200).send({licensesArray});
});
```

I would go with **async/await** if your environment supports it, as it makes things easier to read and lets you program with a synchronous mindset (under the hood it's still asynchronous). If your environment does not support it, you can go with the `Promise.all` approach.

Further reading:

- [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Perfect Perfect.. I got it.